# Python. Active_directory. Create user

Tags: python, active-directory

Does anyone know if it is possible to create new user in Active Directory using python and active_directory module?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The active_directory module you're mentioning doesn't seem to provide said functionality.

Here's a code-snippet using win32com that should help you:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303345-create-an-account-in-ms-active-directory/